# Custom font using CSS3 @font-face not working

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, tumblr

This may seem like a silly question, but do custom fonts that are linked to using `@font-face` also need to be installed locally in order for them to work?

I have the following code:

```
@font-face {font-family:"3dumb";src:url(‘http://static.tumblr.com/wi49tax/8Vmlzz5ja/3dumb.ttf’);}
@font-face {font-family:"2dumb";src:url(‘http://static.tumblr.com/wi49tax/fC0lzz68h/2dumb.ttf’);}

#pages {font-family: "3dumb";
       font-size: 2.2em;
   }
```

The code works on the machine that I have the font installed on (in Safari 5.0.5), but it doesn't work on ay other machine I try it on...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, taking your code literally, it won't work because you use curly quotes rather than straight quotes. Replace the curly quotes with straight quotes and see if *that* works.

Comment: Argh!  I can't believe that worked, I copied that code directly from the tumblr help page.

Answer (score 0):

Your page needs to have access to the font files.  They may be installed locally on your machine but not on the other.

Try http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to generate a font-pck that you can embed in your CSS.